# Difference in covariant derivative and divergence?

Tags: functions, vector-calculus

defining polar Minkowski metric (with indecies down in polar coordinates) as

```
   gdd = {{-1, 0, 0, 0},{0, 1, 0, 0},{0, 0, r^2, 0},{0, 0, 0, r^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2}}
```

and using the code in [Covariant derivative given Christoffel symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155871/covariant-derivative-given-christoffel-symbols) we define Affine connection

```
Γudd[aa_, bb_, cc_] := (1/2)*Sum[guu[[aa,dd]]*(D[gdd[[dd,cc]], clist[[bb]]] + D[gdd[[dd,bb]], clist[[cc]]] - 
  D[gdd[[bb,cc]], clist[[dd]]]), {dd, 1, Length[gdd]}]
```

Then the covariant derivative

```
covDu[A_, a_, b_] := D[A[[a]], clist[[b]]] + Sum[Γudd[a, b, c]*A[[c]], {c, 1, Length[gdd]}];
```

Along with coordiantes and inverse metric

```
clist = {t, r, θ, ϕ};
gUU = Simplify[Inverse[gdd]];
```

Now if we consider the vector (with indices up)

```
EmU = {0,Er[r, θ, ϕ],Eθ[r, θ, ϕ],Eϕ[r, θ, ϕ]}
```

We can calculate the divergence, but this divergence isn't the same as Mathematica's divergence

```
Sum[covDu[Em, a, a], {a, Length[gdd]}] ==  Div[{Er[r, θ, ϕ],Eθ[r, θ, ϕ],Eϕ[r, θ, ϕ]}, "Spherical"]
```

We get non-zero output. How come? Shouldn't they be the same?
Note that this happened when I defined my own Christoffel Symbols and covariant derivative.

Comment: Perhaps the error is given by Mathematica choosing different basis for its divergence, but I can't find which basis it would choose, JacobianDeterminant[] of "Spherical" is the same as the determinant of my metric.

Comment: Just from the first glance, you defined the metrics in polar coordinates, but the divergence calculated in spherical???

Comment: I am not sure if the issue has been resolved or not, some added concern to what @AlexeiBoulbitch pointed out is the following: in the command `Sum[covDu[Em, a, a], {a, Length[gdd]}]` that you gave, `Em` is undefined. so either this is a mistake, or we are missing some code in the OP.

Comment: And another comment, if you run `Div[{Er[r, θ, φ], Eθ[r, θ, φ], 
  Eφ[r, θ, φ]}, "Polar"]` as you have written, it returns [unevaluated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPDGE.png). You need to specify the coordinate system according to the documentation of [`Div`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Div.html). In simple terms  you should have something like ``Div[{Er[r, θ, φ], Eθ[r, θ, φ], 
  Eφ[r, θ, φ]}, {r, θ, φ} ,"Polar"]``. This gives the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGT8v.png)

Comment: Finally, in the way that the code is presented `guu` is **ALSO** unevaluated, so even with the proper definition of `Em` `Mathematica` would make her complaints.

Comment: There's a typo in the next to last of my comments. It should read `"Cylindrical"` rather than `"Polar"`.